# bootstrap class link-dark does not affect

Tags: html, css, class, bootstrap-5

While i'm new to bootstrap i'm getting for my first easy site. Actually i'm stucking on the footer copyright section where the class "link-dark" does not affect.

```
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary text-dark link-dark">
      <div class="text-center p-3">
        © 2021 Copyright:
        <a href="https://foo.bar/">foo.bar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
```

The classes `container-fluid bg-primary text-dark` are affecting, but no the `link-dark`.

I've checked the documentation on the following site, but cant figure out whats are wrong over here, cause their are no limitations.

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/colored-links/

Can anybody answer what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
<!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary text-dark">
      <div class="text-center p-3">
        © 2021 Copyright:
        <a class="link-dark" href="https://foo.bar/">foo.bar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
```

If i want to change the color behavior of the link, the class need to get set on the link element.

Answer (score 0):

This class was added in Bootstrap 5.0 and is not available in any earlier version. Make sure you're using the latest Bootstrap version to be able to use this class.

Comment: The correct Bootstrap version is in use - i got the issue and posted the answer.